# how did the WWE lose the "WWF" trademark to the WWF (World Wildlife Fund)?

Tags: trademark

The WWE, World Wrestling Entertainment, formerly WWF (World Wrestling Federation) is in the entertainment / media industry. They are completely unrelated to the World Wildlife Fund, which is into conservation of wild life.

Comment: do you know what a **Famous Mark** is?

Comment: how does a lawyer argue for a famous mark? I almost never hear about the WWF. by what standard is it famous?

Comment: There's a fairly detailed description of the history in the Wikipedia articles on the two organizations.  There was an agreement, but there have been disputes as well.  It's not like they just lost it out of nowhere.

Comment: There are U.S. trademarks, and there are international trademarks. In the US, you argument may hold, but not in international courts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Because they broke a contract

A little bit of digging gets to the truth. This [blog](https://babyfacevheel.substack.com/p/heres-the-real-story-of-how-the-wwf) probably has the easiest-to-understand summary.

This is the basic timeline:

- The World Wildlife Fund (which I will call the "Charity") was established in 1961 and registered the trademark WWF around that time.
- Titan Sports (which I will call the "Corporation") changed its on-screen name from World Wide Wrestling Federation (WWWF) to the World Wrestling Federation (WWF) in 1979.
- The Corporation introduced the iconic, stylized WWF logo, which was often seen as saying "WF" rather than "WWF" at first glance, even by the judge in the case. This is usually called the “block logo.” You can see the various logos over time [here](https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/WWE). This is the one we are talking about:

[image: WWE Block Logo]

- In 1989, the Corporation filed for an International Class trademark in the United States for the WWF initials in Class 41 (Education and entertainment services). The Charity objected.
- The trademark office or the courts did not resolve the matter; the parties negotiated a settlement agreement executed as a contract. In return for the Charity withdrawing its objection, the Corporation "would not use the mark ‘WWF’ in ‘Times Roman’ typeface when that mark was standing alone, that is, when not used in conjunction with the World Wrestling Federation’s logo or when [in] the context of the World Wrestling Federation Magazine.”
- However, not all was moonlight and roses. The Corporation opposed the Charity's registration in Canada, and the Charity opposed the Corporation's registrations in Japan, Denmark, and Spain before finally seeking an injunction in Switzerland to prevent the publication of the Corporation's magazine.
- The Swiss judge said "the average purchaser wishing to buy a wrestling magazine would hardly mistake it for the 'WWF News' or vice versa" but also "[o]wing to the high degree to which the plaintiff's mark WWF is well known, the public may well get the wrong impression that the plaintiff is in some form associated with the World Wrestling Federation” and granted an interim injunction. This was never appealed nor did either party agitate for a final resolution of the trademark disputes.
- The Charity was extremely concerned that any association with the Corporation, however tangential, could cause them reputational damage. Both parties were steadfast in their position on confusion: the Corporation said there wasn't any, and the Charity said there was.
- At the same time, the Corporation was going through a difficult time, with both it and its CEO being federally indicted for steroid distribution. It has been subsequently hinted that the Charity exploited this in the negotiations, but this allegation was never placed before any court.
- In the end, they negotiated a settlement agreement finalised on 20 January 1994:

  > - Stop using the WWF initials in printed, written, or other visual form, as well is in connection with their business in general. Allowances were made for merchandise and publications approved for production before a certain point.

  > - No longer filing trademarks the WWF initials and cancel existing registrations except for those of Titan’s block logo in any colors.

  > - Cease speaking the WWF initials orally, though they could use it occasionally in contexts like referring to “the current WWF champion.”

  > - Notify business partners that they must exclusively be referred to by the name “World Wrestling Federation.”

  > - The Fund would drop all legal action and not take further action unless the agreement was violated. They would also notify Titan immediately if they learned of any unaffiliated party using the WWF initials in pro wrestling.
- In 1997, the Corporation launched the WWF.com site, adopted a new logo (the scratch logo) in which the two "W"s were more distinct (see below) and, according to the Charity, “more or less used the initials at will and on an increasing scale.” While there seemed to be a deliberate effort to keep the initials out of print magazines, “a deliberate decision seems to have been made to develop the internet business based on a ‘WWF’ brand.”

[image: 1997 WWE Logo]

- In 2002, the Charity took the Corporation to court in the UK for breach of contract, not trademark infringement. They won, the appeals court saying:

> [I]f the Federation wanted to develop a worldwide trade, whether through the Internet or any other means, the letters WWF were a very risky base on which to build it. When it established its website, it was, or should have been, fully aware of that fact. The costs of ‘rebranding’ now, after some five years of development, are entirely attributable to its own decision to take that risk. The scratch logo may be less significant in itself, but it was part of the same strategy. It was likewise a clear breach of the agreement, and the risks were apparent.

In May, the World Wrestling Federation became World Wrestling Entertainment. The first Raw with the new name featured numerous Hardcore Championship changes so Lillian Garcia could hammer home the new name when announcing the winner. Meanwhile, on old video content, the scratch logo and the initials would always be blurred (or muted if spoken), and that went on for over a decade until the settlement was reached. WWF.com forwarded to WWE.com until it didn’t. Then a funny thing happened: The domain lapsed, with the Fund never taking it over, and a fan bought it to use for a WWE discussion forum. You can probably imagine how well that went down.

FYI, [WWF.com](http://ww01.wwf.com/?pid=9POT3387I&pbsubid=d36a3a59-2417-4321-9a2e-c57be9445eb3&noads=http%3A%2F%2Fww01.wwf.com%2F%3Fskipskenzo%3Dtrue&enc_txt=xv538UXbuSRSB3NEFTrMjG6IXor2ep8GQJM4WF9IOgGSYAOgqWjZU6AGGANdfY%2BNO%2Fe5qvhhIFalFnXRJJq9A8Kg5GLO2gyWbVjZMH5K9%2B8%3D&enc_lnk=AB6NvXraMxCk%2BWDC7sE4An9XOv1vmshxAUrO%2BziGKdjjHXqUSgYnG02QbPM%2BiCoh%2F9aQV7FM%2FqY2lPpKpgUVpQ%3D%3D) is available for sale if anyone wants to take the risk.